# Dúvida sobre código de upload

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida sobre esse código de upload.

```
<?php
//SISTEMA DESENVOLVIDO POR LUCIANO ZANITA | LUCIANOZANITA@LIVE.COM

//requerendo o banco de dados a conexão
include "conecta.php";

//PROPRIEDADES DO UPLOAD DO ARQUIVO
$name = $_FILES["logotipo"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["logotipo"]["type"];
$size = $_FILES["logotipo"]["size"];
$temp = $_FILES["logotipo"]["tmp_name"];
$error = $_FILES["logotipo"]["error"];

if ($error > 0)
{
    die("Ouve alguns problemas. ! Codigo do<b></b> Erro: $error.");
}
else
{

 if($type == "video/avi" || $size > 2000000) //imagens que pode ser upload, e tamanho de arquivo maximo
 {
  die("Arquivo não aceito ou tamanho acima do Limite.");
 }
 else
{
move_uploaded_file($temp,"imagens/".$name);
 echo"Arquivo enviado";
} }
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO BancoDedados (logotipo) VALUES ('imagens/$name')");
?>
```

Por oque eu vi ele aceita todos os tipos de upload, mas só faz uma verificação de memoria em arquivos video/avi?

Esse numero que esta ai 2000000 é Megabytes ou KB ?

Comment: Já sei que é bytes, só falta a outra duvida agora :D

Comment: Neste caso você poderá adicionar outras extensões ali, que não queira que faça envio... ou faça então só extensões permitidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode desenvolver da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
//SISTEMA DESELVOLVIDO POR LUCIANO ZANITA | LUCIANOZANITA@LIVE.COM

    //requerendo o banco de dados a conexão
    include "conecta.php";

    //PROPRIEDADES DO UPLOAD DO ARQUIVO
    $name = $_FILES["logotipo"]["name"];
    $type = $_FILES["logotipo"]["type"];
    $size = $_FILES["logotipo"]["size"];
    $temp = $_FILES["logotipo"]["tmp_name"];
    $error = $_FILES["logotipo"]["error"];

if ($error > 0){
    die("Ouve alguns problemas. ! Codigo do<b></b> Erro: $error.");
} else {

    if($type == "video/avi" || $size > 2000000){
        die("Arquivo não aceito ou tamanho acima do Limite.");
    } elseif($type=="image/jpg" or $type=="image/png"){ // Nesta linha você pode adicionar as extensões válidas e permitidas para envio, para descobrir a extensão, consulte a documentação de FILES, dentro do PHP
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"imagens/".$name);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO BancoDedados (logotipo) VALUES ('imagens/$name')");
        echo"Arquivo enviado";
    } 
}
?>
```

Adicione as extensões válidas. Para que conheça o tipo de extensão, consulte a documentação $_FILES no PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Para saber a quantidade de MB que você deseja permitir:
http://pt.calcuworld.com/calculadoras-para-empresas/calculadora-de-bytes/

Comment: Ah agora entendi os arquivos video/avi não serão permitidos...

Comment: Exatamente, na segunda verificação inseri somente os que serão permitidos, ai vai de você incluir quais é do seu desejo.

Comment: Gostei da modificação que você fez, é mais fácil eu falar as que eu vou permitir do que bloquear, pois tem diversas extensões de arquivos no world todo, thanks

Comment: Exatamente, ali está destinado a quais você permite e se quiser adicionar um else, ainda consegue colocar uma mensagem caso não encontre dentro das extensões permitidas.

Comment: Vou usar somente assim, tem algum problema sera no codigo que posso prejudicar ele? if ( $error > 0 ) { die ( "Ouve alguns problemas." ) ; } else { move_uploaded_file ($temp,"upload/".$name) ; echo ( "Arquivo enviado" ) ; }

Comment: Sem passar pelas extensoes? nao teria.. mas podem enviar arquivos maliciosos...

Comment: Vai ser uma coisa bem básica, quero limpar esse código.